# Return a value based on a function in placeholder in oracle Apex

Tags: email, oracle-apex

Sorry if this is a "stupid" question, but I am new to Apex.

I made 2 processes on the create button: one is to insert into the department table and the other one to send an email with some info, among them the department too.
I made an email template and I want to display the department name, not the id which is inserted into the table. So I thought, that maybe I can do that with a function, like in the picture attached(get_department_by_id - returns the name of a department).

[example][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjBag.png

Answer (score 0):

The help function in the builder usually gives enough info. Here is the help for "Placeholder values"

[image]

So only Application, Page Items and System Variables are allowed.

Note: There are multiple places in APEX where you can pass a number of arguments (links, branches, etc) but nowhere the use of functions is allowed.

Comment: I tried with an application item, where I called the function with the item from the page as parameter, like this: 
get_department_by_id(&P7_ID_DEPARTMENT.), but with no result.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What does " where I called the function with the item from the page as parameter" mean ? To set a page item to a value you need a page process or a computation. Example for computation: a computation of type "Expression" with source ```get_department_by_id(:P7_ID_DEPARTMENT)```

Comment: I created a computation with source  get_department_by_id(:P7_ID_DEPARTMENT), but in the email displays as plain text, it doesnt show the name of the department

Comment: This is basic debugging. Create a page process (after that computation and before the process that sends the email with a call) to ```apex_debug``` (check the documentation) with the value of the page item. Then verify the debug logs for a page submit. With this little info it's hard to debug for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me.
I created a computation, with the computation of type "Expression" with source get_department_by_id(:P7_ID_DEPARTMENT) and Condition Type "Request = Expresion 1" with source the name of the button(ex.create).
Thank you Koen Lostrie for the guidance!